# IntelliJ new android gradle plugin (0.14.+)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, build, gradle

I'm trying to use the new android gradle plugin in IntelliJ but I can't seem to build my project using the new gradle plugin.

I modified the dependencies in the application's build.gradle file to `"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'"`, I have updated the gradle to 2.1 and I have updated the build.gradle file in my module.

I keep getting this error in the IntelliJ logs:

```
2014-11-03 16:40:12,864 [ 937413]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5  Build #IU-135.1289 
2014-11-03 16:40:12,864 [ 937413]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - JDK: 1.8.0_05 
2014-11-03 16:40:12,864 [ 937413]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2014-11-03 16:40:12,864 [ 937413]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2014-11-03 16:40:12,864 [ 937413]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - OS: Windows 8 
2014-11-03 16:40:12,864 [ 937413]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Last Action: ShowSettings 
2014-11-03 16:40:13,130 [ 937679]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 5 ms 
2014-11-03 16:40:13,130 [ 937679]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2014-11-03 16:40:13,130 [ 937679]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms 
2014-11-03 16:41:02,813 [ 987362]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05 
2014-11-03 16:41:02,815 [ 987364]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05 
2014-11-03 16:41:02,821 [ 987370]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\ionut.negru\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit8822454065314970200.gradle] 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,002 [ 991551]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Failed to set up Android modules in project 'MyApplication' 
org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException: Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
    at org.gradle.tooling.model.internal.Exceptions.unsupportedMethod(Exceptions.java:33)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getJniDirectories(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.ContentRootModuleCustomizer.addSourceFolder(ContentRootModuleCustomizer.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.ContentRootModuleCustomizer.addSourceFolders(ContentRootModuleCustomizer.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.ContentRootModuleCustomizer.setUpContentEntries(ContentRootModuleCustomizer.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.ContentRootModuleCustomizer.setUpContentEntries(ContentRootModuleCustomizer.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.AbstractContentRootModuleCustomizer.customizeModule(AbstractContentRootModuleCustomizer.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.customizeModule(AndroidProjectDataService.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.access$100(AndroidProjectDataService.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService$1.run(AndroidProjectDataService.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CommandProcessorImpl.executeCommand(CommandProcessorImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CommandProcessorImpl.executeCommand(CommandProcessorImpl.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.access$000(WriteCommandAction.java:33)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.doImport(AndroidProjectDataService.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.importData(AndroidProjectDataService.java:97)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$MyMultiExternalProjectRefreshCallback$1$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:766)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:329)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$MyMultiExternalProjectRefreshCallback$1.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:763)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$5$1.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:364)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:361)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2014-11-03 16:41:07,002 [ 991551]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5  Build #IU-135.1289 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,002 [ 991551]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - JDK: 1.8.0_05 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,002 [ 991551]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,002 [ 991551]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,003 [ 991552]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - OS: Windows 8 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,003 [ 991552]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Last Action: ExternalSystem.RefreshAllProjects 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,290 [ 991839]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 6 ms 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,290 [ 991839]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2014-11-03 16:41:07,290 [ 991839]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms
```

I am doing something wrong ? Or at this moment it isn't possible to use the new android gradle plugin on IntelliJ, althought I've read that IntelliJ should have all the features that Android Studio has.

PS: I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate version and I'm avoiding to move to Android Studio as some features from the Ultimate version won't be available in Android Studio.

[**Update**]
After some more research I found from another SO question that IntelliJ doesn't keep up with android gradle plugin. There is some delay between AS and IntelliJ. More info can be found here: [What is the Android plugin version included in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262344/what-is-the-android-plugin-version-included-in-intellij-idea/26262595#26262595) on @Scott Barta response.

As it seems IntelliJ 13.1.5 supports only com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0. Maybe in a few days/weeks IntelliJ will pull the android gradle plugin from AS and push it into their product.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of [UnsupportedMethodException Android Studio 0.8.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680972/unsupportedmethodexception-android-studio-0-8-9)

You either need to upgrade Android Studio to 0.9 or downgrade the android plugin to lower than 14 in your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have read my question. It is about Intellij with Android plugin 0.14.+

Comment: @IonutNegru - as Android studio *is* Intellij there is a fair chance it may be the same problem.

Comment: The issue is that IntelliJ doesn't automatically pull the updates from the AS repository. They need to update their base before they push the actual updates from Android plugins. AS does the opposite...

Answer (score 2):

Just updating dosn't work for me. what worked is update the beta version than udate in the canary channel after updating the beta version

Just click on **update** then change the channel and the click on oK

Answer (score 0):

just try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22308639/663540

When I update the gradle plugins to 0.14 in build.gradle,I met the error DefaultActivity not found, I try the answer above and finally build successful in IDEA 14.

It seams that you error stack is related to the problem I met.

Comment: Currently I'm on IntelliJ ultimate 13.1.5. I haven't received the update for IntelliJ 14 yet (I have manually checked also and only the preview version is available as an update). If the update won't be available anytime soon I will need to manually get the new version and install it as an separate application.

Comment: actually the 14.0 version is not fully support gradle plugins 0.14 according to the link in your question,so just wait for the update of IDEA

Comment: We can only hope the team from IntelliJ will update the IDE to support it as soon as possible. Until then, the only choice we have is to use Android Studio which is not mature yet.

Comment: Note that the 14.0.2EAP is released which merged the Android Studio 0.9.3 update
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/11/intellij-idea-14-0-2-eap-139-463-is-out/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with build 139.658.4, released on December 4th, 2014 and it's working fine with plugin 0.14.4

If you want to give a try:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP